# Порядок выборки колонок с одинаковыми названиями при объединении двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы: `locality` и `region`. В них есть одноименные поля `name`, `deleted_at` и другие. А также поля с уникальными для каждой таблицы названиями.

В запросе

```sql
SELECT *, locality.*
FROM locality
JOIN region ...
```

я использую `*, locality.*`, таким образом одноименные колонки из `locality` "затирают" `region`: выбирается `locality.name`, а не `region.name`.

Насколько такое поведение стандартизировано? Не будет ли проблем при миграции Postgresql <=> Mysql? При обновлении версии РСУБД поведение может поменяться?

PS. Вариант прописать все поля вручную `SELECT locality.name, region.region_code, ...` не предлагать.

Comment: На некоторых СУБД, например, Firebird, такой запрос завершится ошибкой неоднозначности имени столбца. Там следует использовать `SELECT region.*, locality.*`. В принципе любое поведение, кроме варианта "не предлагать" может сломаться при изменении версии СУБД.

Answer (score 2):

Очень плохая практика указывать в запросе `*`, если только это не тестовый стенд.
Количество полей в таблице может измениться, и ожидающая сторона может попросту упасть.

**Всегда перечисляйте все колонки в указании полей.**

Если очень хочется гибкости указывайте таблицы по очереди:
`SELECT region.*, locality.*`

Но, повторюсь, **так лучше не делать**!

Comment: Указание `*` связано с использованием query builder, который ожидает фильтр в виде класса. Фильтр не знает, какие поля понадобятся. Он только добавляет `JOIN region и WHERE`. Такой дизайн этого билдера. И при добавлении поля, класс фильтра также придется поправить, что не укладывается в SOLID. Я из этих соображений пишу.